# How can I get the error message when a user account has not been successfully saved?

Tags: entities, 10

I'm trying to build a rest API to provide my mobile team to register a user using mobile app. I'm using [www.example.com/entity/user](http://www.example.com/entity/user) for rest API as POST.

I'm able to create the user, but in some cases, the account is not successfully created, for example when the email has been already used for an account. In this case, I need to send out an email with the exact error message.

How can I get the error message returned when the account has not been created?

Comment: Drupal has a REST API. Why are you building a custom one?

Comment: I'm using same one entity/user (sorry, not user/entity edited the question) which is default API in Drupal 10, I wanted to send a better messages back to API response when its get failed

Comment: Better than what?